# 'caret' package error in train(): "all the Accuracy metric values are missing"

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using the 'caret' package to train a model with the 'polr' package (doing an ordinal logistic regression). Here is my setup:

```
fitControl <- trainControl(
    method = "repeatedcv",
    number = 5,
    repeats = 5)

set.seed(825)
ordinallogitfit <- train(BTC ~ 
                           TallyZero3 + LastMove:ConsecUp + LastMove:ConsecDown +
                           TallyUp1:ConsecDown + LastMove:UpMaxPoint, data = training, 
                 method = "polr", 
                 trControl = fitControl,
                 verbose = TRUE)
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :5     NA's   :5  
Error: Stopping
In addition: There were 14 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
warnings()
Warning messages:
1: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: method=logistic Error in family$linkfun(mustart) : 
  Argument mu must be a nonempty numeric vector

2: In glm.fit(X, y1, wt, family = binomial("probit"), offset = offset) :
  no observations informative at iteration 1
3: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
4: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: method=probit Error : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

5: In glm.fit(X, y1, wt, family = binomial("probit"), offset = offset) :
  no observations informative at iteration 1
6: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
7: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: method=loglog Error : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

8: In glm.fit(X, y1, wt, family = binomial("probit"), offset = offset) :
  no observations informative at iteration 1
9: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
10: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: method=cloglog Error : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

11: In glm.fit(X, y1, wt, family = binomial("cauchit"), offset = offset) :
  no observations informative at iteration 1
12: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
13: model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: method=cauchit Error : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

14: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  ... :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

It looks like that very last message is the most important one, but I don't know what to do. My data has no NAs and no infinite values. My response variable is represented as a factor with 3 levels. All of my input variables are integers (not categorical variables, but just integers/counts).

What is the cause of the error and how can I fix it?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: I just tried using the polr() function directly and there is no error - looks like this must be something with the 'caret' package itself.

Comment: can you try adding the tuneGrid like in the solution for this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231087/how-do-i-set-a-model-sub-parameter-named-method-from-carets-train-function

Comment: Essentially you need to indicate to polr you need a logistic model. If it works, I would close this a duplicate.